How to make people look at my question
I currently asked a question: Creating a new attack class for Royal Janisarry in AOE2
But since the last answer no one has actually look or provide some help...
WHat should I do to bring back the question so people can look at it ?

This is covered in the [Help], here specifically.

Also a possible duplicate of Why aren't my questions being well-received?.

If you’ve posted a question that no one has answered, or if no answers adequately help answer your question, then you or someone else can post a bounty.
Posting a bounty on a question costs reputation, however, and you have to have at least 75 rep to post a bounty. Posting the bounty will lose you the amount of rep you set the bounty for. If you don’t give the bounty by accepting someone’s answer, you will not get that rep back.

To clarify: once you post the bounty, that rep is "spent", i.e. you don't get it back. Best case scenario is that your bountied question attracts upvotes which can help cover the cost of the bounty
